# Latex Subfloat has odd text next to figures

Tags: floats, subfloats

I'm using template from sigchi http://www.sigchi.org/publications/chipubform/sigchi-papers-latex-template/view

I'm having problem with subfloats. 
I have three figures and they look like this:

```
chch IMAGE1 chch IMAGE2 chch IMAGE3
```

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\begin{figure*}
\centering
\subfloat[A]
    {\includegraphics[width=2.0inch]{images/MEMS3D}
    \label{WIIMOTESENSOR}}
\subfloat[B]
    {\includegraphics[width=2.0inch]{images/raymond}
    \label{SPACESENSOR}}
\subfloat[C]
    {\includegraphics[width=2.0inch]{images/raymond}
    \label{SPACESENSOR2}}
    \caption{Gyro}
    \label{SENSORS}
\end{figure*}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Full minimal example please. There is no `\subfloat` supported by that template in an unmodified version. Also plase use, say, `\rule{4cm}{4cm}` as your images, we don't have the same iamges as you do.

Comment: @JLDiaz, good catch.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look on our [our starter page](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @JLDiaz  Thank you !!! that was the problem... I knew it was in, but for some reason I was typying inch ... thanks!!!!

Comment: @JLDiaz an answer? :) or else too localized? you decide :)

Comment: you gave me the answer, but I think it is too localized. up to you guys!

Comment: @JLDiaz I think you should make an answer: TL is no longer available as a close option anyway, but I think that is a good answer. and generally applicable `\includegraphics[width=2ptarmigan]{bird}` wuld be another example.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle +1 for the avian example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was caused for the word `inch` as unit. The correct keyword is `in`.

TeX parser expects units at some places after numeric tokens, and it scans the next characters to determine if the units are `pt`, `in`,  `mm`,  `cm`, and so on. As soon as it succesfully parses those two letters it considers the token complete, and subsequent characters are considered part of the next token. So, for example:

```
\vskip 1inch
```

Would produce a vertical space of `1in`, followed by the letters `ch`, which would cause TeX to start a new paragraph. The same problem appears if `\setlength` is used.

In your particular case, the `\subfloat` macro evaluates twice the argument (presumably the first time to box it and measure its dimensions, and the second time to actually typeset it). This explains why `ch` appears repeated as in `chch`.

Of course the same problem will happen with any other of TeX units, but I find difficult to make a similar mistake with the others. No one would write `centimeters` instead of `cm`, and anyway in this case TeX would produce an error, because the two first letters (`ce`) do not succesfully parse into any of TeX units. Other cases such as `cms` look unlikely.